# Passing arguments to a macro hidden in the text

Tags: macros, expansion, expl3

#### Context:

I'm trying to write a macro that behaves somewhat like C's `printf` family of functions. For instance, the following C code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Hello %s! Today's a good day to write obscure %s macros.\n",
           "World","TeX");
}
```

prints

```
Hello World! Today's a good day to write obscure TeX macros.
```

by replacing the first `%s` by `"World"` and the second `%s` by `"TeX"`.

I'm trying to provide a similar syntax:

```
\Printf{Hello \%! Today's a good day to write obscure \%\ macros.}
       {world,\TeX}
```

which should print the same sentence in TeX. Right now I'm failing because TeX is not C `:)`

---

#### The problem:

I can't find a way to pass the items in the second argument of `\Printf` to `\%` because the `\%` macro can be hidden anywhere in the middle of the text.

A simple definition for `\Printf` and `\%` would be:

```
\def\Printf#1#2{%
  #1% What do I do with #2?
}
\def\%{% How do I define this macro?
  :(%
}
\Printf{Hello \%! Today's a good day to write obscure \%\ macros.}
       {world,\TeX}
\bye
```

then the output would be: [image]

The question is: how do I define `\Printf` and `\%` such that it prints the correct sentence?

---

#### Requirements (because I'm picky `:P`):

- The strongest requirement is that I would like the `\Printf` function to be expandable, so that:

  ```
  \edef\tempa{\Printf{Obscure \%\space Macros.}{TeX}}
  \show\tempa
  ```

  would print:

  ```
  > \tempa=macro:
  ->Obscure TeX Macros..
  ```
- It has to work inside brace groups. I tried a delimited macro approach that kind of worked, but failed miserably if the `\%` appeared inside a brace pair<sup>1</sup>.
- I would also like engine independence.
- The syntax, on the other hand, can change slightly. That is, the `\Printf{text}{replacement}`. I would like to keep the `\%` thingy `:)`

---

#### What I tried:

<sup>1</sup>Here's my attempt using `\%` delimited macros. I like this approach better because I don't have to redefine the `\%` control character anywhere. The downside is that it fails miserably when the `\%` token appears inside a braced group. What a bold...

```
\input expl3-generic.tex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_item:nn { nf }
\cs_set_eq:NN \clistItem \clist_item:nf
\cs_new:Npn \Printf #1 #2
  { \__printf_step:nnn { 0 } { #2 } { #1 } }
\cs_new:Npn \__printf_step:nnn #1 #2 #3
  { \__printf_step:nnw { #1 } { #2 } #3 \% \q_nil }
\cs_new:Npn \__printf_step:nnw #1 #2 #3 \% #4
  {
    #3
    \quark_if_nil:NF #4
      {
        \exp_args:Nf \__printf_percent:nn
          { \int_eval:n { #1 + 1 } } { #2 }
        \exp_args:Nf \__printf_step:nnw
          { \int_eval:n { #1 + 1 } } { #2 }  #4
      }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__printf_percent:nn #1 #2
  { \clist_item:nn { #2 } { #1 } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\Printf{Hello \%! Today's a good day to write obscure \%\ macros.}
       {world,\TeX}

\Printf{Oh, \%, my macro doesn't work {\bf with \%\ text}. What a \%\dots}
       {drat,bold,shame}

\bye
```

This prints:

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Totally insane, of course, but doable! Here, I use the same approach as in for example `\text_lowercase:n`. We step through the tokens, examining each one. There are three cases, a brace group, a space, and a 'normal' token. In the latter case, we split between `\%` and anything else. The only tricky part is tracking the substitution number inside brace groups. I do that by keeping the tracking number at the 'top level', and 'passing back' the number from inside any brace groups before they are added to the 'output'.

```
\input expl3-generic.tex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \Printf #1#2
  {
    \exp:w \exp_not:o
      {
        \exp_after:wN \exp_end: \exp:w
        \exp_args:Nf \__printf_outer:n { \__printf:nnn { 1 } {#1} {#2} }
      }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__printf_outer:n #1
  { \__printf_outer:nn #1 }
\cs_new:Npn \__printf_outer:nn #1#2
  {
    \exp_end:
    #1
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__printf:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \group_align_safe_begin:
    \__printf_loop:w
      #2 \q_recursion_tail \q_recursion_stop {#3}
    \__printf_result:nn { } {#1}
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__printf_loop:w #1 \q_recursion_stop
  {
    \tl_if_head_is_N_type:nTF {#1}
      { \__printf_N_type:N }
      {
        \tl_if_head_is_group:nTF {#1}
          { \__printf_group:nw }
          { \__printf_space:w }
      }
    #1 \q_recursion_stop
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__printf_N_type:N #1
  {
    \quark_if_recursion_tail_stop_do:Nn #1
      { \__printf_end:w }
    \token_if_eq_meaning:NNTF #1 \%
      { \__printf_N_type:w }
      {
        \__printf_output:nw {#1}
        \__printf_loop:w
      }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__printf_N_type:w #1 \q_recursion_stop #2 \__printf_result:nn #3#4
  {
    \exp_args:Nff \__printf_N_type:nnnnn
      { \clist_item:nn {#2} {#4} }
      { \int_eval:n { #4 + 1 } }
      {#1} {#2} {#3}
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__printf_N_type:nnnnn #1#2#3#4#5
   {
    \__printf_loop:w #3 \q_recursion_stop
      {#4}
      \__printf_result:nn { #5 #1 } {#2}
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__printf_group:nw #1#2 \q_recursion_stop #3 \__printf_result:nn #4#5
  {
    \exp_args:Nf \__printf_group:nnnn
      { \__printf:nnn {#5} {#1} {#3} }
      {#2} {#3} {#4}
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__printf_group:nnnn #1#2#3#4
  { \__printf_group:nnnnn #1 {#2} {#3} {#4} }
\cs_new:Npn \__printf_group:nnnnn #1#2#3#4#5
  {
    \__printf_loop:w #3 \q_recursion_stop
      {#4}
      \__printf_result:nn { #5 {#1} } {#2}
  }
\exp_last_unbraced:NNo \cs_new:Npn \__printf_space:w \c_space_tl
  {
    \__printf_output:nw { ~ }
    \__printf_loop:w
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__printf_output:nw #1#2 \__printf_result:nn #3
  { #2 \__printf_result:nn { #3 #1 } }
\cs_new:Npn \__printf_end:w #1 \__printf_result:nn
  {
    \group_align_safe_end:
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\Printf{Hello \%! Today's a good day to write obscure \%\ macros.}
       {world,\TeX}

\Printf{Oh, \%, my macro doesn't work {\bf with \%\ text}. What a \%\dots}
       {drat,bold,shame}

\bye
```

Comment: Basic idea here is from `\__tl_act:NNNnn`, used internally in the kernel: one of Bruno's. You can't directly use that here, which is much the same as `\tl_lower_case:n`, due to the need to keep extra data on the stack. But it's fundamentally Bruno's approach ...

Comment: Note: I've not worried about preventing `f`-type expansion of the replacement text. That would be doable (if for example you want to examine the tokens in the case of adding `\TeX`), but I'll leave as an exercise for the reader :) [Hint: see `\tl_lower_case:n`]

Answer (score 12):

*Regular expressions* are your friend! You can step through the `clist` of arguments and use `\regex_replace_once:nnN` to replace each one in turn in a token list for the printed text to produce:

[image]

This approach is shorter too! Here's the code:

```
\input expl3-generic.tex

\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l_printf_args_clist
\tl_new:N \l_printf_tl
\cs_new:Npn \Printf #1 #2
{
  \tl_set:Nn \l_printf_tl {#1}
  \clist_set:Nn \l_printf_args_clist {#2}
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_printf_args_clist {
    \regex_replace_once:nnN { \c{\%} } {##1} \l_printf_tl
  }
  \tl_use:N \l_printf_tl
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\Printf{Hello \%! Today's a good day to write obscure \%\ macros.}
       {world,\TeX}

\Printf{Oh, \%, my macro doesn't work {\bf with \%\ text}. What a \%\dots}
       {drat,bold,shame}

\bye
```

Hmm, although this may not fit the expandability requirement...

Comment: Hmmm... I didn't think of regular expressions. They do make things work. But the `\regex` functions aren't expandable (as you noted yourself while I was writing this). But it's a nice idea nonetheless :)