# Can I have a delimited macro with a literal # in the parameter text?

Tags: macros, tex-core

I'm trying to define a macro which grabs everything until the next `#` (parameter token).
My twisted imagination wants something like this:

```latex
\def\test#1###2{(#1)[#2]}
\test hello#{world}
```

to grab `hello` in `#1` (delimited by `#`) and `world` in `#2` (brace delimited) and then print

```
(hello)[world]
```

However I'm failing (miserably) because no matter what combination of `##` I try, TeX yells back:

```
! Parameters must be numbered consecutively.
<to be read again> 
                   ##
l.1 \def\test#1##
                 #2{(#1)[#2]}
?
```

so I guess that simply writing down the `#` in there is not the way to go.

Is it possible somehow to have a `#`-delimited macro?

Comment: why the `#` not simply `\test hello{world}` ? :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I was trying to scan the parameter text of a macro looking for its arguments one by one.

Comment: it's hard (not really possible) to even find out how many arguments a macro has, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305806/is-there-a-reliable-way-to-get-the-number-of-arguments-of-a-command

Comment: "Scan parameter text of a macro" -- if this means evaluating the result of `\meaning\macro`: With `\meaning` you don't have information about category codes. The meaning of the following  macros looks the same but the 1st one does process two args and the 2nd one has just a delimiter and does not process args: 1) `\def\macro#1#2{#1 text #2}`  2) ``\catcode`\#=12\relax\def\macro#1#2{#1 text #2}`` . Also, you are not bound to using hashes for denoting args. You can use any character after assigning catcode 6 to it. You can also use control-sequences/active chars let equal to catcode-6-chars.

Comment: @UlrichDiez Hm, now I see I did not phrase my question properly. What I wanted to achieve (and already changed my mind) was to scan a definition before the actual definition took place (something like `\scandef\def\test#1{something with #1}`), not with `\meaning`, so the hashes do have catcode 6 and, in this case, it doesn't matter which character they are because TeX will not allow this. Thanks for the input, though :-)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik But this is feasible to some degree: Have `\scandef` catch both the definition-command, the macro-name and the parameter-text into an argument via `#{`-notation and then iteratively examine that argument token-wise, taking into account the fact that parameter-text cannot contain `{`... You can, e.g., implement a loop which counts the hashes in the sequence formed by the definition-command, the control sequence-name and the parameter-text.

Comment: @UlrichDiez Yes, I changed my approach to token-by-token like you said before even asking the question. I asked more out of curiosity than anything else :-). I tried the `#`-delimited approach first precisely because the parameter text can't have braced groups, so it wouldn't skip any `#1{#2}` and I think the code is simpler that way.

Comment: @UlrichDiez It's actually for a draft of a package I did (more for personal use than anything else). It allows you to `\named\def\test#[name]{Hello #[name]!}`. It's pretty stupid, but it makes life easier when you have macros with lots of arguments and change their order once every two lines of code :P Here's the [source](https://www.dropbox.com/s/swtdng8horm0hj7/namedef.dtx?dl=0), if you want to take a look.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I often encounter the problem which you approach with your package. In daily usage I tend to write "underlying macros" and "user-level-macros": A user-level-macro via `\setkeys` only process a mandatory keyval-argument for (re)defining some control-word-tokens which have meaningful names and then calls its belonging  "underlying macro" which in turn does not process any argument at all but instead uses those (re)defined control-word-tokens with the meaningful names... Of course this approach does not work out with macros that are intended to work in pure-expansion-contexts.

Comment: @UlrichDiez Precisely :-) I'm writing the interface I describe [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/457787/134574), which I'm making fully expandable. At the user-level the macro has only two arguments, so it's fine. However internally there are some macros which take up to 7 arguments (I'll probably optimize this later), and my brain cannot keep track of all of them that easily :)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik If I got it right, you need a routine which within (almost) arbitrary token sequences expandably replaces (almost) arbitrary token sequences by digits denoting argument numbers  while within the token sequence (definition-texts) where things shall be replaced by argument-number-digits, several levels of brace nesting/of nesting of matching arbitrary catcode-1/2-character-token-pairs could occur. By now I don't see a perfect slution for this where, e.g., arbitrary catcode-1/2-character-token pairs are left in place and are not replaced by { respective }.  Besides this...

Comment: ... I don't see an expandable method for, e.g., distinguishing active characters let equal to their non-active pendants from these pendants. E.g., I don't know a method for expandably distinguishing catcode-6-A from catcode-13-A after ``\catcode`\A=6\relax`` `\let\A=A` ``\catcode`\A=13\relax`` `\let A=\A` unless using predefined macros where catcode-13-A is used as argument delimiter. You'd need such a macro for each character/code-point which in the input can possibly occur. On utf8-machines you'd need a lot of such macros. In this case distinguishing `\A` from `A` when `\escapechar` is -1...

Comment: @UlrichDiez Those are indeed good points to consider. However the interface will be split in two main types; one which scans arbitrary text and expands ``\catcode`[=1\catcode`]=2 \printf{Integer \%02d and \textbf[float \%6.4f]}{3,pi}`` to `Integer 03 and \textbf{float 3.1416}`, and a more dedicated interface, `\printf_f_type:nnnn{}{6}{4}{pi}` which should be safer in a programming level. The former interface is supposed to be more user-level, where you don't expect weird catcode settings, but if a user does that in an actual document they should know what they are signing up for ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The TeXbook, page 203, says in the first doubly dangerous paragraph

> Now that we have seen a number of examples, let’s look at the precise rules that govern TeX macros. Definitions have the general form
>
> `\def`⟨control sequence⟩⟨parameter text⟩`{`⟨replacement text⟩`}`
>
> where the ⟨parameter text⟩ contains no braces, and where all occurrences of `{` and `}` in the ⟨replacement text⟩ are properly nested. Furthermore the `#` symbol has a special significance: In the ⟨parameter text⟩, the first appearance of `#` must be followed by `1`, the next by `2`, and so on; up to nine `#`’s are allowed.

There is *no* way for the parameter text to contain a (category code 6) `#`, because of the rule stated above.

As usual in the TeXbook, this is not the complete truth; in the second doubly dangerous bend on page 204 one reads

> A special extension is allowed to these rules: If the very last character of the ⟨parameter text⟩ is `#`, so that this `#` is immediately followed by `{`, TeX will behave as if the `{` had been inserted at the right end of both the parameter text and the replacement text. For example, if you say ‘`\def\a#1#{\hbox to #1}`’, the subsequent text ‘`\a3pt{x}`’ will expand to ‘`\hbox to 3pt{x}`’, because the argument
>   of `\a` is delimited by a left brace.

However, this special extension has no favorable consequence towards your aim.

Comment: Oh, _must be followed_ :/

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Yes, not the weaker “should” or “ought to”.

Comment: although (not unusually for the texbook) that rule isn't actually completely true (you can follow the last `#` by `{` rather than a digit). So that dangerous bend on its own wouldn't be enough to confirm it wasn't possible (but it isn't possible:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, I added the relevant quotation.

Comment: There is module 476 in `tex.pdf`, which I _sort of_ understand (because I already know what it does (sort of)). It first looks for a left brace, if it's not then steps a counter `t` and if the grabbed token isn't equal to `t` the error message in the question is printed.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik That's it: the rule disallows `#` not followed by the expected digit except at the end.

Comment: The last `#` can be followed by any token whose meaning *at the time of defining* equals the meaning of the catcode-1-`{`. Even if after defining the meaning of that token gets changed, that token will be used as a delimiter which will be left in place: 
`\let\Weird={`
`\def\test#1#\Weird #1 weird is }`
`\def\Weird{\TeX!}`
`\test Really\Weird`
`\bye`

Comment: @UlrichDiez Yes, I know the feature, but it's a particular that's not really connected to the question at hand. I was thinking to add this exception to the rule that the replacement text has to start with an explicit `{`, but decided not to. Your comment is valuable on this respect.

Answer (score 5):

You can't really do what you ask, but you can ignore the `#` while parsing the arguments, then get rid of it:

[image]

```
\def\test#1#{\def\tmp##1{#11}\zz}
\def\zz#1{(\tmp{})[#1]}

\test hello#{world}

\bye
```

Comment: “You can't really do” is acceptable (although frustrating). Is there anywhere that explains this (not that I'm doubting you ;-)?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik egreg's answer shows some sort of documentation, although as i commented there the texbook often"clarifies" rules later so it is hard to use it as a definitive source, there is always tex-the-program.....