# Trying to understand the definition of \newcommand (complex handling of parameter tokens)

Tags: macros, arguments, definition

I'm still trying to understand how exactly tex parses documents. This time I'm trying to understand all the parameter-tokens-handling in `\newcommand` and friends, which looks like black magic to me - the crux here seems to happen in `\@yargdef` and `\@yargd@f`, which can be found in `latex.ltx` lines 868 and 877 respectively. The aim is obviously to create the parameter string that will ultimately be following a `\def\foo`, but I don't understand how this works.

To explain where I think my problem is, I'll have to explain my thinking a little, unfortunately.
So: If I do `\newcommand\foo[2]{\bar}`, then as far as I can tell, this ultimately (after various checks for whether `\foo`
 is already defined and checking for optional arguments etc.pp.) expands to `\@argdef\foo[2]{\bar}`.

I'll go step by step how I read the definitions:

- `\@argdef` is defined via:

  ```
  \long\def\@argdef#1[#2]#3{%
  \@ifdefinable #1{\@yargdef#1\@ne{#2}{#3}}}
  ```

  So we end up with `\@yargdef\foo\@ne{2}` (leaving `{\bar}`).
- `\@yargdef`is defined thus:

  ```
  \long \def \@yargdef #1#2#3{%
  \ifx#2\tw@
  \def\reserved@b##11{[####1]}%
  \else
  \let\reserved@b\@gobble
  \fi
  \expandafter
  \@yargd@f \expandafter{\number #3}#1%
  }
  ```

  which defines `\reserved@b` as `\@gobble`
  and ultimately expands to `\@yargd@f{2}\foo` (leaving `{\bar}`).
- Now `\@yargd@f` is the weird part. It is defined via:

  ```
  \long \def \@yargd@f#1#2{%
  \def \reserved@a ##1#1##2##{%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter#2\reserved@b ##1#1%
  }%
  \l@ngrel@x \reserved@a 0##1##2##3##4##5##6##7##8##9###1%
  }
  ```

  So the expansion in my case should be (if I'm not mistaken?):

  ```
  \def\reserved@a #12#2#{%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\foo\reserved@b #12%
  }%
  \l@ngrel@x \reserved@a 0#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9#2
  ```

  So in the *application* of `\reserved@a`, the first argument should be `0#1#` and the second argument should be... empty, I guess, since the immediate following token is already `#`...? Leaving `3#4#5#6#7#8#9#2{\bar}` as the next tokens?

This must be where my thinking goes wrong, because if I pretend that string before the `{\bar}` *isn't* there, the rest makes sense:
`\reserved@a` then expands to
`\expandafter\def\expandafter\foo\reserved@b 0#1#2` - `\reserved@b` is defined as `\@gobble` which just eats the first token it finds, so the expansion of that should be `\def\foo#1#2` - which would be followed by the `{\bar}`.

So apparently I'm interpreting the argument-string of `\reserved@a` wrong? What exactly is the second argument of `\reserved@a` in its application, if not empty? The only possible other explanation I can think of is that it eats to the *next* `#`-token, but even then, it would only eat the `#3` part and leave a whole string of parameter tokens...?

am I expanding `0##1##2##3##4##5##6##7##8##9###1` or the `##1#1##2##` in the definition of `\reserved@a` wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct except for what the `#{` parameter does.

When TeX sees a `#` in the `<parameter text>` of a macro (as in `\def\macro<parameter text>{<replacement text>}`), the following token can be either a digit in the range 1–9, or a `{`. When the parameter is "the dreaded weird `#{` parameter", then TeX behaves as if the delimiter of the previous argument was a `{` (since you can't use a `{` in the `<parameter text>`).

In this definition (remember the `{\bar}` is still in the input stream):

```latex
\def\reserved@a #12#2#{%
\expandafter\def\expandafter\foo\reserved@b #12%
}%
\l@ngrel@x \reserved@a 0#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9#2{\bar }
```

when `\reserved@a` expands, `#1` will be, as you said, `0#1#`, and `#2` will be everything up to the next `{`, and *not* empty, so `#3#4#5#6#7#8#9#2`, delimited by the `{` in `{\bar }`. This definition of `\reserved@a` effectively throws away the remaining parameter tokens. So your "pretend[ing] that string before the `{\bar}` *isn't* there" was actually correct. The rest of the code executes as you assumed.

---

A quote from *The TeXbook*, about the `#{` parameter:

> A special extension is allowed to these rules: If the very
>   last character of the `<parameter text>` is `#`, so that this `#` is
>   immediately followed by `{`, TeX will behave as if the `{` had been
>   inserted at the right end of both the parameter text and the replacement text.
>   For example, if you say '`\def\a#1#{\hbox to #1}`', the
>   subsequent text '`\a3pt{x}`' will expand to '`\hbox to 3pt{x}`', because
>   the argument of `\a` is delimited by a left brace.

Comment: Other links about `#{`: [Macros with # as the last parameter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13333/82917) and [“Grab to #{” macro arguments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39525/82917)

Comment: @campa Those are good references, indeed. Thanks!

Comment: Oooooh, I had no idea that `#{` was special - that was my problem. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @DennisMüller You're welcome :-) Yes, that is the only exception to the "`#` must be followed by 1--9" rule. See egreg's answer to my question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/491304/134574), and perhaps §476 in TeX-the-program (`texdoc tex`) to see where does that exception come from.

Answer (score 9):

I've already dealt with the problem in my book on LaTeX programming. My example is slightly different, but it's easier to copy. ;-) Suppose we have

```
\newcommand{\xyz}[2]{ab#1cd#2ef}
```

This becomes

```
\@star@or@long\new@command[2]{ab#1cd#2ef}
```

As there is no `*` after `\new@command`, this does `\let\l@ngrel@x=\long` and `\@star@or@long` disappears. Now `\new@command` is expanded, yielding

```
\@testopt{\@newcommand\xyz}0[2]{ab#1cd#2ef}
```

This becomes

```
\kernel@ifnextchar[{\@newcommand\xyz}{\@newcommand\xyz[{0}]}[2]{ab#1cd#2ef}
```

The purpose is to add `[0]` if the number of arguments is not given. Since there is a `[`, we get

```
\@newcommand\xyz[2]{ab#1cd#2ef}
```

Now comes the lookup for a further optional argument, which I skip, and we obtain

```
\@argdef\xyz[2]{ab#1cd#2ef}
```

The token `\xyz` is checked for definability; if it is not definable we get the error message, otherwise

```
\@yargdef\xyz\@ne{2}{ab#1cd#2ef}
```

and this is where the real fun starts:

```latex
\ifx\@ne\tw@
  \def\reserved@b#11{[##1]}
\else
  \let\reserved@b\@gobble
\fi
\expandafter\@yargd@f\expandafter{\number2}\xyz{ab#1cd#2ef}
```

This defines `\reserved@b` to be `\@gobble` and leads to

```
\@yargd@f{2}\xyz{ab#1cd#2ef}
```

Recall the definition of `\@yarg@def`:

```latex
\long\def\@yargd@f#1#2{%
  \def\reserved@a##1#1##2##{%
    \expandafter\def\expandafter#2\reserved@b##1#1}%
  \l@ngrel@x\reserved@a0##1##2##3##4##5##6##7##8##9###1%
}
```

The arguments are `#1=2` and `#2=\xyz`, so we get (double `##` are here reduced to a single `#`)

```latex
\def\reserved@a#12#2#{\expandafter\def\expandafter\xyz\reserved@b#12}
\l@ngrel@x\reserved@a0#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9##1{ab#1cd#2ef}
```

The first argument to `\reserved@a` is delimited by `2`, the second argument by `{`. This is a particular feature of TeX: the final argument can be delimited by the opening brace of the replacement text.

Thus the first argument is, in our case, `0#1#`. Since `\l@ngrel@x` is `\long` it triggers the expansion of `\reserved@a` with the stated arguments:

```
\long\expandafter\def\expandafter\xyz\reserved@b0#1#2{ab#1cd#2ef}
```

Since `\reserved@b` is `\@gobble`, we end up with

```
\long\def\xyz{ab#1cd#2ef}
```