# Use of named arguments instead of numbers in LaTeX

Tags: macros, context, arguments

ConTeXt has a .mkvi file extension for modules (roughly similar to LaTeX packages) which allows to use named arguments like:

```
\def\foo[#parameters]#content{ #parameters ... #content ...}
```

instead of

```
\def\foo[#1]#2{#1 ... #2 ...}
```

Not really a difference, but it has an advantage that macros tend to be more readable.
Are there any packages or functionalities which allow the same for LaTeX?

Comment: `\def\foo[#1]#2{#1 ... #2 ...} %where #1=parameters, %2=content` seems to be enough clear.

Comment: The context extension requires imho luatex. As latex wants to support more engines (pdftex, xetex, ptex, uptex) this can not be implemented.

Comment: ConTeXt preprocesses the file before even running LuaTeX on it, so I don't think this can work with just LuaTeX.

Comment: I wrote something like that some time ago to assist on another project of mine.  Some internal macros started to have too many arguments and I was changing their order too often, so keeping track of the argument numbers was becoming a nuisance (and often lead to errors). The code is here, if you're interested: https://github.com/PhelypeOleinik/namedef. To build the docs just run `pdflatex namedef.ins`, and a `.sty` file should be generated.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I've had to install a dozen packages to compile docs (I work with a minimal LaTeX installation). However, I'm pleased to see catcode trickery. It looks ConTeXt enough to my taste. I'll accept your comment if you make it an answer.

Comment: @JairoADelRio Sorry about that, I have a full install, so I don't mind adding packages.  But that's for the docs only: the package itself depends only on `l3kernel`, which is now loaded in the LaTeX kernel anyway, so virtually no dependencies. Maybe I should upload it to CTAN...

Comment: There are some good answers in [macros - Naming \newcommand arguments for code clarity - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/570892/naming-newcommand-arguments-for-code-clarity) as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I wrote something like that some time ago to assist in another project of mine. Some internal macros started to have too many arguments and I was changing their order too often, so keeping track of the argument numbers was becoming a nuisance (and often lead to errors).

To solve that, I wrote the [`namedef`](https://ctan.org/pkg/namedef) package, that allows you to change from (an admittedly boring example):

```
\def\Say#1 to #2%
  {#1, #2!}
```

to

```
\named\def\Say#[greeting] to #[whom]%
  {#[greeting], #[whom]!}
```

The advantage I saw in this syntax is that if you decide to swap the order of `#[greeting]` and `#[whom]` in the parameter text, you don't have to change them in the replacement text—the advantage of semantics over syntax :-)

The code works by scanning the definition for `#6[⟨name⟩]`, replacing them by numbers, and then handing the translated tokens for TeX to perform the definition.

The code is hosted at https://github.com/PhelypeOleinik/namedef.  To build the `.sty` file, run `tex namedef.ins`, and to build the documentation, run `pdflatex namedef.ins`.  The generated `.sty` file can be used in LaTeX with `\usepackage{namedef}`, or in other formats with `\input namedef.sty`.

Comment: Nice. Did you think to `#<name>#` instead of the brackets?

Comment: @egreg Hm... I didn't think of that. It would be a bit tricky in case you have single parameter tokens in the replacement text, like `\edef\foo#name#{\string#then#name#}` (not sure it is possible to distinguish the right case reliably). Also according to [this bloke](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/491304/134574), I can't have a macro delimited by a `#`, so it makes the implementation a bit more complicated :-) That said, since it's possible to change the delimiter when necessary, it should be possible to use that syntax...