# How to name command arguments

Tags: preamble, arguments, definition

Is there a way to give a "name" to the arguments of a command and use them in its definition? What I'd like to do is to be able to get the value of an argument with a "label" like `#myargname` instead of `#<number>`. For example, I'd like to define a `\foocommand` like

```
\newcommand{\foocommand}[#normal,#bold,#italics,#smallcaps,#emphasis]%
           {#normal \textbf{#bold} \textit{#italics} \textsc{#smallcaps} \emph{#emphasis}}
```

instead of

```
\newcommand{\foocommand}[5]%
           {#1 \textbf{#2} \textit{#3} \textsc{#4} \emph{#5}}
```

Comment: But the same input should prevail? As in `\foocommand{one}{two}{three}{four}{five}`, with no indication of what their components mean? Or would you rather have `\foocommand{bold=two, smallcaps=four, emphasis=five, italics=three, normal=one}`?

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/549462/2388

Comment: If you have an up-to-date TeXLive, you should have the `namedef` package installed, otherwise check it out [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/namedef). Section 4.1 of the documentation (“Extended \newcommand”) features an interface like the one you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can. Here's a proof of concept.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\newparametercommand}{smO{}m}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF { #1 }
   {
    \ntakwetet_newparametercommand:Nnnn \cs_set_nopar:cV { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
   }
   {
    \ntakwetet_newparametercommand:Nnnn \cs_set:cV { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
   }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__ntakwetet_replacement_tl
\int_new:N \l__ntakwetet_index_int
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \cs_set:Nn { cV }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \cs_set_nopar:Nn { cV }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \ntakwetet_newparametercommand:Nnnn
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__ntakwetet_replacement_tl { #4 }
  % double the #
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \cP. } { \cP\#\cP\# } \l__ntakwetet_replacement_tl
  % index for the parameters
  \int_zero:N \l__ntakwetet_index_int
  % substitute any item in the list of parameters with #<n>
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #3 }
   {
    \int_incr:N \l__ntakwetet_index_int
    \exp_args:Nne \regex_replace_all:nnN
     { ##1 } % search
     { \exp_not:n { \cP\# } \int_eval:n { \l__ntakwetet_index_int } } % replace
     \l__ntakwetet_replacement_tl
   }
  % define a temporary macro with #1=\cs_set:cV or \cs_set_nopar:cV
  #1 {__ntakwetet_temp:\prg_replicate:nn { \l__ntakwetet_index_int } { n } } % name
   \l__ntakwetet_replacement_tl % replacement
  \cs_new_eq:Nc #2 {__ntakwetet_temp:\prg_replicate:nn { \l__ntakwetet_index_int } { n } }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newparametercommand\foo[#abc,#def]{#abc,#def}

\newparametercommand*\baz[#abc,#def]{#abc--#def}

\newparametercommand{\foocommand}[#normal,#bold,#italics,#smallcaps,#emphasis]{%
  #normal \textbf{#bold} \textit{#italics} \textsc{#smallcaps} \emph{#emphasis}%
}

\begin{document}

\foo{a}{b}

\baz{a}{b}

\foocommand{normal}{bold}{italics}{smallcaps}{emphasis}

\end{document}
```

Each item in the comma separated list is searched for in the replacement text and substituted with `#<n>` for the current index.

Limitation: a keyword cannot have another keyword as initial segment. So `#a` and `#aa` would not work. Also one cannot use more than nine arguments, of course.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not automatic, but simple and easy.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\foo}[2]% #1=\first, #2=\second
{\bgroup% make definitions local
  \def\first{#1}%
  \def\second{#2}%
  Arguments are \first{} and \second.
\egroup}

\begin{document}
\foo{A}{B}
\end{document}
```

---

Alternate, but prone to errors.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\foo}[1]% #1 = TeX definitions
{\bgroup% make definitions local
  #1
  Arguments are \first{} and \second.
\egroup}

\begin{document}
\foo{\def\first{A}\def\second{B}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDITED to remove the deficiency of the prior approach.

If you don't mind changing your syntax in the following ways:

1. Change your symbolic-argument identifier from `#` to something that is not cat 6, here done with `!`
2. Define the new command with `\symbolicnewcommand`, since `\newcommand` is already defined with a different syntax.

Thus, the syntax is something like:

```
\symbolicnewcommand{\foocommand}%
  [!normal,!bold,!italics,!smallcaps,!emphasis,!boxed]%
  {!normal{} \textbf{!bold} \textit{!italics} 
   \textsc{!smallcaps} \emph{!emphasis} \fbox{!boxed}}
```

Unlike my prior approach, this approach doesn't merely mimic the `\newcommand` behavior, but recreates it, by converting the symbolic arguments into explicit `#1`, `#2`, etc., (i.e., **NOT** placed inside a `\def`).

Here is the MWE.  Note that in the `\meaning` of the defined macro, the symbolic arguments, for example, `!normal`, is converted into an explicit `#1`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{listofitems,tokcycle}
\newtoks\mytoks
\newtoks\tmptoks
\def\OPENSgroup{\OPENSgroup}% quark
\def\CLOSEgroup{\CLOSEgroup}% quark
\def\SPACEquark{\SPACEquark}% quark

\newcommand{\addtotoks}[2]{#1\expandafter{\the#1#2}}
\newcommand{\xaddtotoks}[2]{%
  \expandafter\addtotoks\expandafter#1\expandafter{#2}}

\makeatletter
\long\def\symbolicnewcommand#1[#2]#3{%
  \readlist*\arglist{#2}%
  \stripgroupingtrue%
  \tokcycle{\addcytoks{##1}}%
    {\addcytoks{\OPENSgroup}\processtoks{##1}\addcytoks{\CLOSEgroup}}%
    {\addcytoks{##1}}{\addcytoks{\SPACEquark}}{#3}%
  \mytoks\expandafter{\the\cytoks}%
  \foreachitem\z\in\arglist[]{%
    \expandafter\setsepchar\expandafter{\z}%
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\tmp\expandafter{\the\mytoks}%
    \readlist*\cmdlist{\tmp}%
    \mytoks{}%
    \foreachitem\zz\in\cmdlist[]{%
      \ifnum\zzcnt=1\relax\else%
        \tmptoks{&}%
        \xaddtotoks\tmptoks{\zcnt}%
        \xaddtotoks\mytoks{\the\tmptoks}%
      \fi%
      \xaddtotoks\mytoks{\zz}%
    }%
  }%
%
  \setsepchar{&}%
  \expandafter\readlist\expandafter\cmdlist\expandafter{\the\mytoks}%
  \mytoks{}%
  \foreachitem\z\in\cmdlist[]{%
    \ifnum\zcnt=1\relax\else\addtotoks\mytoks{####}\fi%
    \xaddtotoks\mytoks{\z}%
  }%
%
  \expandafter\addBracesSpaces\expandafter{\the\mytoks}%
%
  \def\tmp{\newcommand{#1}[\arglistlen]}%
  \expandafter\tmp\expandafter{\the\mytoks}%
}

\newcommand\addBracesSpaces[1]{\mytoks{}\fooaux#1\endfoo}
\def\fooaux#1{%
  \tctestifx{\endfoo#1}{}
  {\tctestifx{\OPENSgroup#1}{\Z}
  {\tctestifx{\SPACEquark#1}{\addtotoks\mytoks{ }}
  {\addtotoks\mytoks{#1}}\fooaux}}%
}
\makeatother

\def\Z#1\CLOSEgroup{\addtotoks\mytoks{{#1}}\fooaux}

\symbolicnewcommand{\foocommand}%
  [!normal,!bold,!italics,!smallcaps,!emphasis,!boxed]%
  {!normal{} \textbf{!bold} \textit{!italics} 
   \textsc{!smallcaps} \emph{!emphasis} \fbox{!boxed}}
\begin{document}
\meaning\foocommand

\foocommand{To be,}{or not}{to be?}{That}{is the question.}{123}
\end{document}
```

[image]