# Def inside NewDocumentCommand fails?

Tags: macros, xparse

I'd like to rename arguments like `#1` into something like `\ies@firstStar` to have less error prone programming and less variable renaming when changing the parameters of a function. However doing something like `\def\ies@firstStar{#1}` fails, any idea what's wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\myTest}{s}{
  \bgroup% make definitions local
  \def\ies@firstStar{#1}%
  \IfBooleanTF{\ies@firstStar}{%
    One star
  }{%
    No star
  }
  \egroup
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\myTest
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the reason of such indirection. Why not using directly `\IfBooleanTF{#1}`? This seems like an XY-question; can you please give a better example that justifies the approach?

Comment: @egreg Because after I use #1 everywhere in the function. And first I will soon forget what #1 is (which is error prone), and second if I add a single new parameter at the beginning of my function definition I need to redefine ALL my variables... I already think TeX is the most obfuscated language ever, no reason to add more mysterious numbers ;-)

Comment: @egreg Putting stuff like `#1` into a variable is not completely unreasonable, especially if you are going to program something where the value of this variable might change along the way. In most non-TeX languages, it is, after all, quite common to use many auxiliary local variables in function definitions.

Comment: @tobiasBora Sorry, I can agree with nothing you're saying. You're misusing the tools.

Comment: @egreg It could be, but then I'm curious to see how I could use the tools better. Like in python, if I define a function `def myfunction(lastname,firstname)` and suddently decide that it should be `def myfunction(firstname,lastname)`, I have a single line to change. In LaTeX, I have all the code of the function to update. And don't you agree that `lastname` is waaay clearer that `#1` later in the code?

Comment: @tobiasBora No, I don't agree. But, hey, I've been programming in TeX for 30+ years. Python and TeX are different languages. It's useless to try forcing one being like the other.

Comment: @egreg I actually agree with tobiasBora to some extent about the fact that the TeX syntax is strange and alien, and I, too, would prefer named parameters to numbered ones. And if I use any other programming language, I use local variables inside function definitions all the time. But in TeX, and only in TeX, this is considered dangerous and bad style (and makes your macro unexpandable if it was not already).

Comment: @Gaussler Use Lua… ;-)

Comment: @egreg Perhaps that’s the solution. `;-)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\let` instead of `\def` to avoid the `\expandafter`s.  In the case of `\def`, the *replacement text* of `\ies@firstStar` is `\BooleanFalse` or `\BooleanTrue`.  In the case of `\let`, `\ies@firstStar` actually *is equivalent* to `\BooleanFalse` or `\BooleanTrue`.

As Gaussler notes, `\let` can only assign a single token.  Therefore, this approach works because the `s` argument will never be more than a single token.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\myTest}{s}{%
  \begingroup% make definitions local
  \let\ies@firstStar=#1%
  \IfBooleanTF{\ies@firstStar}{%
    One star%
  }{%
    No star%
  }%
  \endgroup
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\myTest
\myTest*
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As in my answer, you might want to change `\bgroup...\egroup` to `\begingroup...\endgroup`.

Comment: @Gaussler While I generally do use begin/end versions, I'm not sure of the difference in this case.  Nonetheless, I gladly changed it.

Comment: Well, in math mode, it makes a difference.

Comment: @Gaussler That is true that, in math mode, a difference can arise between `\begingroup` and `\bgroup`, though in the case of detecting a star version, I'm not sure it amounts to any real risk.

Comment: It should also be remarked that this only works because, in this case, the value of `#1` is a single token. If you do it with an `m`-type argument, you’re gonna be in trouble.

Comment: Actually, it seems the value is something that expands to some variant of `\Gamma` or `\Delta`, depending on the value. Not sure why. Didn’t test it in detail.

Comment: @Gaussler It's that the standard TeX fonts have `\Gamma` and `\Delta` in slots 0 and 1, but that's really only reflecting that the values were never meant to be typeset

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes You are introducing spurious spaces. Remove the one in `#1 %`

Comment: @egreg Thank you.  I guess I was of the false understanding that you were allowed one "free" space  after `\let` assignments.

Comment: There can be optional spaces around the (optional) `=`.

Comment: "Therefore, this approach works because the s argument will never be more than a single *."  that implies #1 could be * or nothing (\let would not work in that case) it just works becase it is always a single token `\BooleanFalse` or `\BooleanTrue`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 3):

Internally, I’m not sure exactly how `\IfBooleanTF` works, but the following solves the problem. However, at least for this simple example, I fail to see how this makes the code more readable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\myTest}{s}{
  \begingroup% better to use this than \bgroup...\egroup
  \def\ies@firstStar{#1}%
  \expandafter\IfBooleanTF\expandafter{\ies@firstStar}{%
    One star
  }{%
    No star
  }
  \endgroup
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\myTest
\myTest*
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! Arg, there is no way to avoid expandafter? I really hate this as it's very error prone ^^'

Comment: @tobiasBora Perhaps. You’ll have to ask someone who knows how `\IfBooleanTF` works internally. The only solution I can provide is this one. `;-)`

Comment: Ok thanks! In case no other solution is found I'll accept it!

Comment: every use of this will add two space tokens to the output. (three if you include the one after `star`)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I was just copying what the OP asked for. Perhaps they wanted those spaces for some reason.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19541789#19541789

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to understand the need for such an indirection.

Anyway, the *current* implementation of the `s` argument type is that, if `s` is the first argument, the value assigned to `#1` in case no `*` comes along is `\BooleanFalse`, `\BooleanTrue` if there is a `*`.

Then the *current* implementation of `\IfBooleanTF{#1}{True}{False}` chooses the true or false branch according on whether `#1` is `\BooleanTrue` or `\BooleanFalse`. Next you might want to know that *currently* `\BooleanTrue` and `\BooleanFalse` are `\chardef` tokens, so they're not expandable.

But the user/programmer should ***not*** rely on this. In future releases this might change; not likely to happen, but, hey! Who knows?

Besides, I can't see any advantage whatsoever in `\IfBooleanTF{\ies@FirstStar}` over `\IfBooleanTF{#1}`. To the contrary, I see several disadvantages, for instance that you need grouping to avoid timing expansions or macro clobbering.

Why doesn't your `\def` work? Because `\ies@FirstStar` is not the same as `\BooleanTrue` or `\BooleanFalse`: it is a macro expanding to either of them (and `expl3` uses `\ifx` for the check, not `\if` which wouldn't work, so no expansion is performed). If you use, as suggested, `\let` instead of `\def`, the code *seems* to work, but it might stop to with a future release of `expl3`. On the contrary, `\IfBooleanTF{#1}` is guaranteed to work forever.

Comment: “Forever” is a very big promise. Not sure how it’ll work after the Sun expands and eats up the Earth. `;-)` Also, I think the `\expandafter` solution is also guaranteed to work forever.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I understand better now the reason of the fail. That said, talking only about *readability/maintainability/debugging*, and not about TeX internals, if you have just a single parameter, sure it is not that of a problem to keep `#1`. Now, when you have multiple parameters (including multiple parameters which come with a `BooleanFalse/BooleanTrue` definition, which is my case), codes with `#n` are very hard to read and maintain, I guess you can agree on that. Also, is there any other edge case of using `\let`?

Comment: @tobiasBora you can almost never use `\let\foo=#1` it just works in the specific implementation of the `s` type as `#1` is always exactly one token (and never two tokens or empty) so let failing isn't an edge case it is the expected result.

Comment: @tobiasBora Whilst it is the case that a lot of languages use named parameters, TeX doesn't. That means it's hard to get away from knowing how to use them. In particular, assignments prevent working in an expansion context: in those places, you _have_ to use `#1`, etc. I guess I'd say this is a feature of the language one has to learn to live with.

Comment: @tobiasBora You may want to look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/549462/4427