# expl3 macro to expandably iterate over a list and apply a macro on each item

Tags: macros, expl3, expansion

Can someone show me how to make the following macro (`\applyeach`) expandable using `expl3`, if it is possible?

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{applyeachposition}
\newcommand\applyeachmacro{}


% #1 : macro to apply
% #2 : multi-args
\newcommand\applyeach[2]{
    \setcounter{applyeachposition}{0}
    \renewcommand\applyeachmacro{#1}
    \applyeachrecu#2|\nil
    \renewcommand\applyeachmacro{}
}


\def\applyeachrecu#1|#2\nil{
    \stepcounter{applyeachposition}
    \applyeachmacro{#1}
    \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax\else
        \applyeachrecu#2\nil
    \fi
}


\newcommand\decoone[1]{%
    [(\textbf{#1})] \quad%
}

\newcommand\multiapply[1]{%
    \applyeach{\decoone}{#1}
}
 

\begin{document}

\multiapply{1|12|123|1234}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You need the counter?

Comment: The counter is used for extra traitment (typically to do special stuf with the first argument).

Comment: What's the expected output? And what's the purpose of the counter? Sorry, but one cannot answer without knowing what you expect and *why* you add some seemingly unneeded details. Anyway, you cannot have something expandable if you need to set counters.

Comment: @egreg I use this macro to decorate trees by applying a graphical macro to the parts : doc here (https://github.com/typensee-latex/tnsproba/blob/master/tnsproba/tnsproba-doc%5Bfr%5D.pdf : see section 6) and related codes here (https://github.com/typensee-latex/tnsproba/blob/master/factory/02-tree/01-tree.sty at the end) and here (https://github.com/typensee-latex/tnscom/blob/master/factory/07-metaprog/02-multi-args.sty). The name of the macros are different.

Comment: This seems a typical XY question. You've never explained why you want to use `|` as a delimiter, nor what the output `1|12|123|1234` is used for. Now we discover that it's probably an intermediate step. Please, avoid piling up questions and disclose ***what*** you're trying to do.

Comment: @egreg You're right. I will try to be more specific in the future.

Comment: @egreg I use the pipe `|` for macros proposing an unknown numbers of semantic arguments. For example, I have a macro `\coord` for coordinates and I just type `\coord{x_1}` for 1D-space, `\coord{x_1 | x_2}` for 2D-space `\coord{x_1 | x_2 | x_3}` for 3D-space and so on...

Comment: Without the requirement of being expandable `tokcycle` works quite well, among other options -- see [macros - How to iterate through a token list to make characters uppercase, while preserving spaces? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516889/how-to-iterate-through-a-token-list-to-make-characters-uppercase-while-preservi/516931#516931)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the ability to change the delimiter, the definition is pretty straightforward.  Though note that, as egreg says, setting a counter is an assignment, and assignments are *not* expandable, so you can't use them.  You have to increase a number “on the fly” and pass that to the macro, but not as a counter.

The macro itself splits the argument at a `|` and applies a given function to that, until the end of the loop is reached.  Adding a `\prg_do_nothing:` (and removing it later) takes care of braced items and spaces around the argument.  If you need to change the delimiter then the code will get more complicated.

I defined `\multiapply<cmd>{<list>}` such that it iterates on the `|`-separated `<list>` and applies `<cmd>` to each item.  The `<cmd>` needs to take two arguments: `#1` is the number of the item in the list, and `#2` is the item itself.

> [image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \multiapply { m +m }
  { \mbc_multiapply:Nn #1 {#2} }
\cs_new:Npn \mbc_multiapply:Nn #1 #2
  {
    \__mbc_multiapply:nNw { 0 } #1
      | \prg_do_nothing: #2 | \q_recursion_tail | \q_recursion_stop
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__mbc_multiapply:nNw #1 #2 | #3 |
  { \exp_args:Nof \__mbc_multiapply:nnN {#3} { \int_eval:n {#1+1} } #2 }
\cs_new:Npn \__mbc_multiapply:nnN #1 #2 #3
  {
    \quark_if_recursion_tail_stop:n {#1}
    \exp_not:e { \exp_not:N #3 {#2} { \tl_trim_spaces:n {#1} } }
    \__mbc_multiapply:nNw {#2} #3 | \prg_do_nothing:
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\decoone[2]{%
  Item #1: [(\textbf{#2})]\quad}

\begin{document}
\multiapply\decoone{ 1 | 12 | 123 | 1234 }
\end{document}
```

Comment: This makes me think that I really need to work with expl3 in some cases like the one in this post. Thanks a lot. I will study this answer seriously and the other answers you give to me.

Comment: @projetmbc Glad you liked it!  In this particular example, there is very little _actual_ `expl3` code (other than the `_` and `:` in the syntax).  For this one you can copy some definitions and make the core in LaTeX2e style: https://pastebin.com/raw/Vdy0JACf  But as you can see in that link, the amount of auxiliaries you need to copy from `expl3` is _larger_ than the code you have to write (and this is a very simple example!), so the advantage of `expl3` is the large amount of tools it provides you (and the far more readable syntax).  If you have any questions, _do_ ask :-)

Comment: What is the simplest way to ignore trim the initial and final spaces of the parts separated by the pipes ?

Comment: @projetmbc Do you want space-trimming by default or to enable it with some option, like `\multiapply*`?

Comment: I only need a default behaviour. That's the way I will use it.

Comment: @projetmbc Okay.  In that case, adding `\tl_trim_spaces:n` does the job.  See the edit

Comment: What is the meaning of `+`  in `+m` ?

Comment: @projetmbc That makes the argument `\long` (as in `\long\def\macro#1{(#1)}`).  Try removing the `+` then do `\multiapply\decoone{1|2\par 3|4}`. It allows paragraph breaks (blank lines) in the argument.

Comment: Thanks. That is very useful.