# expl3 macro to expandably iterate on a list and apply a macro on each pair of items

Tags: macros, expl3, expansion

Can someone show me how to make the following macro (`\applycouple`) expandable using `expl3`, if it is possible?

This question is similar to [this post of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/557632/6880).

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{applycoupleposition}
\newcommand\applycouplemacro{}

% #1 : macro to apply
% #2 : multi-args
\newcommand\applycouple[2]{
    \setcounter{applycoupleposition}{0}
    \renewcommand\applycouplemacro{#1}
    \applycouplerecu#2|\nil
    \renewcommand\applycouplemacro{}
}


\def\applycouplerecu#1|#2|#3\nil{
    \stepcounter{applycoupleposition}
    \applycouplemacro{#1}{#2}
    \if\relax\detokenize{#3}\relax\else
        \applycouplerecu#2|#3\nil
    \fi
}

\newcommand\decocouple[2]{%
    (#1)[#2]%
}

\newcommand\multiapplycouple[1]{%
    \applycouple{\decocouple}{#1}
} 

\begin{document}

\multiapplycouple{1|12|123|1234}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite similar to the implementation in my answer to your other question, but this one takes two arguments, so we need to add two `\q_recursion_tail`.  Also another intermediary macro is used to insert a `\prg_do_nothing:` in the second item to avoid losing spaces and braces.

> [image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \multiapplycouple { m +m }
  { \mbc_multiapply_pair:Nn #1 {#2} }
\cs_new:Npn \mbc_multiapply_pair:Nn #1 #2
  {
    \__mbc_multiapply_pair:nNw { 0 } #1
      | \prg_do_nothing: #2 | \q_recursion_tail | \q_recursion_stop
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__mbc_multiapply_pair:nNw #1 #2 | #3 |
  { \__mbc_multiapply_pair:nNww {#1} #2 | #3 | \prg_do_nothing: }
\cs_new:Npn \__mbc_multiapply_pair:nNww #1 #2 | #3 | #4 |
  { \__mbc_multiapply_pair:oofN {#3} {#4} { \int_eval:n {#1+1} } #2 }
\cs_new:Npn \__mbc_multiapply_pair:nnnN #1 #2 #3 #4
  {
    \quark_if_recursion_tail_stop:n {#2}
    \quark_if_recursion_tail_stop:n {#1}
    \exp_not:e { \exp_not:N #4 {#3} { \tl_trim_spaces:n {#1} } { \tl_trim_spaces:n {#2} } }
    \__mbc_multiapply_pair:nNww {#3} #4 | \prg_do_nothing: #2 | \prg_do_nothing:
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__mbc_multiapply_pair:nnnN { oof }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\decocouple[3]{Item #1: (#2)[#3]\quad}

\begin{document}
\multiapplycouple\decocouple{ 1 | 12 | 123 | 1234 }
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. The small changes are instructive. I will try the next time to start alone the expl3 version.

Comment: @projetmbc Added space trimming here as well :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have done it by myself. ;-)

Comment: It seems that `\quark_if_recursion_tail_stop:n {#1}`. I have seen that by using ``\quark_if_recursion_tail_stop_do:Nn {#1} {--KO--}`` instead.

Comment: @projetmbc You want `\quark_if_recursion_tail_stop_do:nn` (note the `:nn` _vs._ `:Nn`):  at that point in the code you don't know that `#1` is a single token (and often it is not!), so you can't use an `N` argument there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing that.